# Mongoose model how to have an array as property which contains same model as parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So what I'm trying to do is I want to create a Note object inside note I have a subnote property, I want to have the subnote to be able to be as the same type as the parent model, Right now I'm achieving this by creating two same models with different names and both of them referencing each other for e.x this is the way I'm doing it:

Note schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const noteSchema = new Schema({
  icon: {
    type: String,
  },
  banner: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  sub_note: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "sub_notes",
  },
  content: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "blocks",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = Note = mongoose.model("notes", noteSchema);
```

SubNote schema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const subNoteSchema = new Schema({
  icon: {
    type: String,
  },
  banner: {
    type: String,
  },
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  user_id: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    required: true,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  sub_note: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "notes",
  },
  content: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "blocks",
    },
  ],
});

module.exports = SubNote = mongoose.model("sub_notes", subNoteSchema);
```

But I'm not sure if the above method is the proper way to do it..., Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

u can achieve this by simply doing this

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
 
  sub_note: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "notes",
  },

});

module.exports = Note = mongoose.model("notes", noteSchema);
```

or simply using "this" keyword

```
const noteSchema = new Schema({
 
  sub_note: this

});

module.exports = Note = mongoose.model("notes", noteSchema);
```

Comment: How can I find the notes inside sub_notes and add notes to it?